# Handle multiple events in JQuery not working, submit event hangs

Tags: jquery, events, jquery-events, onsubmit

I require to add 3 events.

1. To hide a field on page load.
2. To hide a field based on radiobutton value
3. To do some processing when user clicks submit button

But, when I add the code, submit stops working. But, when I remove the jQuery handling for point 1 and point 2 mentioned above, submit works fine. Please check and let me know if there are any mistakes. Your help is greatly appreciated.

HTML Code:

```
<form action="/BGPAsService/port/save" method="post" id="portform" >
                <fieldset class="form">

<div  id="port_rule" class="fieldcontain  required">
    <label for="portRule">
        Port Rule
        <span class="required-indicator">*</span>
    </label>
    <input type="text" id="portrulevalue" name="portRule" maxlength="80" required="" value="" />

</div>

<div id="portradio" class="fieldcontain required">
    <label for="PortOption">
        Port Option
        <span class="required-indicator">*</span>
    </label>
    
     <input type="radio" name="PortOption" value="value" class="fieldcontain" id="portradiovalue" />Port Value&nbsp;
    

     <input type="radio" name="PortOption" value="range" class="fieldcontain" id="portradiovalue" />Port Range&nbsp;
    

</div>

<div id="start_port" class="fieldcontain required">
    <label for="portStart">
        Port Start
        <span class="required-indicator">*</span>
    </label>
    <input type="text" name="portStart" maxlength="5" required="" value="" id="portStart" />

</div>

<div id="end_port" class="fieldcontain required">
    <label for="portEnd">
        Port End
        <span class="required-indicator">*</span>
    </label>
    <input type="text" name="portEnd" maxlength="5" required="" value="" id="portEnd" />

</div>
</fieldset></form>
```

Jquery Code:

```
           $(document).ready(function(){
                $("#port_rule").hide();

                 $('#portradio').on('click',function(e) {
                   if ($(':radio[name= "PortOption"]:checked').val() == 'value') {
                       $("#end_port").hide();
                   }else{
                       $("#end_port").show();
                   } 
               });

                $('#portform').on ('submit', function(event) {
                    alert("test");
                    var portrule = "";
    
                    if ($(':radio[name= "PortOption"]:checked').val() == 'value'){
                        portrule = portrule.concat('=');
                        portrule = portrule.concat($('input:text[name= "portStart"]').val());
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        portrule = portrule.concat('>=');
                        portrule = portrule.concat($('input:text[name= "portStart"]').val());
                        portrule = portrule.concat('&<=');
                        portrule = portrule.concat($('input:text[name= "portEnd"]').val());
                    }
                    
                    document.getElementById("portrulevalue").value = portrule;
                    
                });

           });
```

Comment: The best way to hide an element on page load is to add `display:none` in your CSS.

Comment: Check your JavaScript console for errors. http://jsfiddle.net/mblase75/Z3qgs/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The hidden field named `portRule` is marked as `required` in your HTML, so the browser is trying to validate it *before* your JS code is run. When it doesn't find a value there on submit, it tries to focus on it -- but can't, because it's hidden. Then a JavaScript error is thrown and your code stops working.

Make the field not required:

```
 <input type="text" id="portrulevalue" name="portRule" maxlength="80" value="" />
```

Or else run your code when the relevant form fields are changed, instead of when the form is submitted:

```
 $('[name="PortOption"],[name="portStart"],[name="portEnd"]').on('change', function (event) {
        var portrule = "";
        // etc.
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mblase75/LxqH7/

Comment: I am using grails. So, I made portRule as hiddenField(<g:hiddenField type="text" name="portRule" value="" id="portrulevalue"/>) and endPort as not required(<g:textField name="portEnd" maxlength="5"/>). Anyways, I need to add custom validation not to allow null if the port option is "Range"

Comment: One more thing -- your radio buttons shouldn't have the same ID (`portradiovalue`)